# TypeScript - How can i deal with multiple IFs

Tags: typescript, if-statement

I was trying to do a *"multiple filter"* in TS, So...

If i send *nothing*         -> **it returns all products normally;**

But if i send some *params* -> **it returns products filtered by the params.**

(I used colors just for the example)

```
async load(params: params): LoadProducts.Result => {
  const products = [];

  if (params) {
    if (params.red != undefined) // products.push( ...load.redProducts() );
    if (params.blue != undefined) // products.push( ...load.blueProducts() );
    if (params.green != undefined) // products.push( ...load.greenProducts() );
    if (params.yellow != undefined) // products.push( ...load.yellowProducts() );
  } else {
    // products.push( ...load.products() );
  }

  return products;
}
```

Type of request:

```
type params = {
  filter?: {
    red?:  boolean;
    blue?: boolean;
    green?: boolean;
    yellow?: boolean;
  };
};
```

Example of request:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "red": true,
    "blue": true
  }
}
```

How can I deal with the multiple IFs to verify the params, because each has its own function to load and I want to add more filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but based on what you *have* shown, you can use a (map-like) array of tuples and iterate over it:

```ts
const colorFns = [
  ['red', load.redProducts.bind(load)],
  ['blue', load.blueProducts.bind(load)],
  // etc...
] as const;

async load(params: params): LoadProducts.Result => {
  const products = [];

  if (params) {
    for (const [color, fn] of colorFns) {
      if (params[color] != undefined) products.push(...fn());
    }
  } else {
    // products.push( ...load.products() );
  }

  return products;
}
```

Comment: Side note: `params[color] != undefined` is probably not enough as `false` is also not `undefined`. You would probably want `if (params[color])` or change the type from `red?:  boolean;` to `red?: true` (so it's always either missing or `true`, never `false`).

Answer (score 1):

If there are **lots** of filters, the primary thing is probably to avoid repeating yourself. So I would make the functions that do the loading drive the process: You define an object with those functions `as const`, then derive your possible filters from that. Here's an example (see inline comments):

```typescript
// Placeholder for your product type
type Product = {
    name: string;
    type: string;
};

// The functions that do the loading of individual types
const loaders = {
    async red() {
        return [{ type: "red", name: "Red 1" }];
    },
    async blue() {
        return [{ type: "blue", name: "Blue 1" }];
    },
    async green() {
        return [{ type: "green", name: "Green 1" }];
    },
    async yellow() {
        return [
            { type: "yellow", name: "Yellow 1" },
            { type: "yellow", name: "Yellow 2" },
        ];
    },
} as const;

// A function that loads everything
const loadAll = async () => {
    const allLoaders = Object.values(loaders);
    return (
        await Promise.all(allLoaders.map(loader => loader()))
    ).flat();
};

// The types of filters we might have
type FilterType = keyof typeof loaders;

// The params type
type ParamsFilters = {
    [Key in FilterType]?: boolean;
};
type Params = {
    filter?: ParamsFilters;
};

// A function that asserts a string key is a valid key for `loaders`
function assertIsLoaderKey(key: string): asserts key is keyof typeof loaders {
    if (!(key in loaders)) {
        throw new Error(`Expected key for 'loaders', got "${key}"`);
    }
}

// The class this is apparently in
class Example {
    async load(params: Params): Promise<Product[]> {
        let products: Product[];

        // If we have filters...
        if (params.filter) {
            // ...run them
            products = (
                await Promise.all(
                    Object.entries(params.filter)
                        .filter(([key, flag]) => flag)
                        .map(([key]) => {
                            assertIsLoaderKey(key);
                            return loaders[key]();
                        })
                )
            ).flat();
        } else {
            // No filters, load everything
            products = await loadAll();
        }

        return products;
    }
}

// Example usage
const e = new Example();
e.load({
    filter: {
        red: true,
        blue: true,
    },
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnUAzZ2BPZAV2wAdNk1jYAXUWgs+AKEeYkurtAF5QA3i1AjQAO2gBbeAC5QAZ1qYAlmIDmAbmGj2shUtWaWAXy0sQoACqJ4uYmLrLkY+Q0TR6aZG9uRk0NENQZBxQVUCAN2VqaEgGJnh5FlhnRVA-AKxXfiFRUGh5AgdQTHg0AAoASkFtPJFS2lIxUABtAXjmOQAiUrQugBpxKT0ugCUy0ABGLtBjAF0tPON+2vzC4oAjSGJ4Kpq60Qam1vbdbq2dgaHpboAhbdtp2YXV5dWCothQNVL4MT3cgcSvBGphmm0OiMfvA-lcJDdQF0AOK-ZpPeaLURvPIfYoEeCQPwAdwBqzyRzBrTJQNOCW6+MJyCJcOG3QAmgTiVMZtigXlaZ1EQziSyEV0OYyiaAAEw8lZ8l5LFbGNagFIuWhmCwAQTsDloTmatHc9AyaFc8AiWAIxsMyVSpv8aG1hL4a0+oD2vAAfPtROq0rFIAAZJ1ZN0AeQ2ACt4HQAHQRWI7eTlM1ZSqY+og47lakiaBE6DKejgSiSZTyeDxoPlIOhzKYeTxyTQMhpsPYH3pTtVSqVVaVeM4GC0KpaUwscxgay2XSuEK4ZSQWjhom2CtqRD0dxWtgJUAAMWXq8wlgP-AA1vAiKFdIv002tTObKAyNBMFJXLp9xxwB+v2PFdwxyVYWgAaRvMJmiA09z2YOYAH45A2ZBUHgaAxAnLRdAgADJGyP0RBwE8sGQvDPwI2CsmwqcdT1RxnDcDw1irTBaFcaB9BUdRQGvAgwk40Ak0gaI+KgvBsAAA0feQpJYHB7EY5oCjY2gAEl5AbDBMEgghyn4uRFB4tRKjkVSsA48SBMrazF3vUJZKIsJQnKABCAyoNUHtG3kftnLyY1KClMR4ClABRTBKEwcopPCgAPZg6AmfjcHwUAAHJZIywY1GQegugAEgEfjjC6KTM1eEw6JfWxYBgeRv0QWzbLbd9SjEWhIBssRkga1wEqkMhIFsQEC3WL4zXKdqvzkf9KL8uby0reAAB4yyoGhaBaOZfTGuoRvoChNroeQlpO7aXnzUALHU0J11AXdbBI4Cm3jd7ruUVyZoI4dSMwap9r5Cx3vjTB7B8SRrryY7uCs-g8z5PlC2LUtlqrGtCURpGcajWMEz+AxEmm-Dmxe08BxxqnRD+17ynKFp+MGEdoDUOZqm7FnTOh6madbdsGf49m+D2nnebqCz2M07SsD0zyCEq8XxYpZpZMZm85nHMXeeMSmlb1nGhxZsdFaBFUCSrAKgQsAA5bxyayQYzVAS1rVtdRtdhrbCJRksfOdLHTYOYwpz5FW3y4b2s1marp1AQbJGG2xiHkVnWADehbH4UKIvioaRq16spv2h3MDkIHDjKOQlB2eUgQuPQa-gOuRDeXWNCAA)

*(That uses the relatively-new [`flat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). It's [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#browser_compatibility) by even vaguely recent versions of modern browsers, but may need polyfilling for old ones.)*